# Unable to rename file using PHP

Tags: php, file, rename, move

Hi wrote simple code to rename my files at server but always getting error as below

```
rename(/public_html/mystore/images,/public_html/mystore/images/test.jpeg): No such file or directory in /home/innovero/public_html/mystore/move.php on line 18
```

Below is PHP Code for rename,

```
<?php
   

/* Store the path of source file */

$filePath = '/public_html/mystore/test.jpeg';
      
/* Store the path of destination file */

$destinationFilePath = '/public_html/mystore/images/test.jpeg';
    

/* Copy File from images to copyImages folder */
    if( !rename($filePath, $destinationFilePath) ) {  

    echo "File can't be moved!";  

}  

else {  

    echo "File has been moved!";  

} 

  

?>
```

What is wrong in my code, My move.php is lying in mystore folder and i wanted to move files from mystore to images folder which is sub folder of mystore. pls help

Comment: A leading-slash would imply that the files are stored at the root of the filesystem, not relative to the current script

Comment: Can you suggest what is correct way of writing path.

Comment: updated error with replacing / to ./ as rename(./public_html/mystore/images,./public_html/mystore/images/test.jpeg): No such file or directory in /home/innovero/public_html/mystore/move.php on line 18

Comment: Then use the full path: `/home/innovero/public_html/...`

Comment: What file exactly are you trying to copy/move here? From `$filePath = '/public_html/mystore/images';`: is `public_html/mystore/images` a file?

Comment: sorry I mistyped, I wanted to move a file from mystore to images folder. I edited my code in question. I wanted to move tests.jpeg from mystore folder to images folder.

Answer (score 0):

You copy dir to file
copy /public_html/mystore/images to /public_html/mystore/images/test.jpeg

Try

```
rename(/public_html/mystore/images/test-old.jpg, /public_html/mystore/images/test-new.jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to rename the directory not the file

Try this code:

```
<?php
  $filePath = '/public_html/mystore/images/test.jpeg';    
  $destinationFilePath = '/public_html/mystore/images/newtest.jpeg';

  if(rename($filePath, $destinationFilePath) ) {  
      echo "File has been moved!";  
  }else {
      echo "Unable to move file";  
}

?>
```

Comment: do you double check the file?

Comment: Need full address like this /home/innovero/public_html/mystore/test.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Finally started working with below code

```
<?php
if(file_exists('/home/innovero/public_html/mystore/test.jpg')){
   
    rename('/home/innovero/public_html/mystore/test.jpg','/home/innovero/public_html/mystore/images/test.jpg');
}else{
    echo "No File";
}
```